# React - override state by exists object properties

Tags: reactjs, object, state

I have state with properties initialized with empty string, because im putting these into form inputs. Additionaly I get object from Firebase with properties matching with state but not every one exists. I would set state properties by properties of this object if properties exists.

Here is necessary example:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
      user: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        gender: "",
        address: {
          street: "",
          city: "",
          state: ""
        }
      }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const newObjectFromFirebase = {
      firstName: "Lucas",
      address: {
        city: "London"
      }
    }
    this.setState(newObjectFromFirebase);
  }
  render() {
    const stateJson = JSON.stringify(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
      {stateJson}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to get state with override properties in only these properties which exists in object from firebase. Otherwise I would like to keep the previous state. Currently state properties  are completely overwritten by new object.

Thats what I want:

```
user: {
        firstName: "Lucas",
        lastName: "",
        gender: "",
        address: {
          street: "London",
          city: "",
          state: ""
        }
      }
```

Thats what I have:

```
user: {
        firstName: "Lucas",
        address: {
          city: "London",
        }
      }
```

Any smart solution or library ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the spread syntax `...` like this:

```
const newObjectFromFirebase = {
  firstName: "Lucas",
  address: {
    city: "London"
  }
}
this.setState(prevState => {
    user: {
        ...prevState.user,
        ...newObjectFromFirebase,
        address: {
            ...prevState.user.address,
            ...newObjectFromFirebase.address
        }
    }
});
```

This will merge the 2 objects together and override the state.

Comment: No Problem. If you dont know how the objects look like, you can also use a deepmerge function from lodash or one [I wrote](https://codepen.io/Domino987/pen/ZEzOEBZ?editors=0010)